# Como fazer um filter a partir de dados do Json

Tags: javascript, json, filter

Boa tarde, sou iniciante em JavaScript, estou montando um projeto de enciclopédia de pokemons e quero fazer um filtro de busca pelo nome do pokemon, porém não está rodando e gostaria de ajuda. Não sei se estou errando na hora de pegar os dados do json ou do input.
Obrigada.

Parte do Json:

```
{
  "pokemon": [{
    "num": "001",
    "name": "bulbasaur",
    "generation": {
      "num": "generation i",
      "name": "kanto"
    },
    "about": "Bulbasaur can be seen napping in bright sunlight. There is a seed on its back. By soaking up the sun's rays, the seed grows progressively larger.",
    "img": "https://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/001.png",
    "size": {
      "height": "0.71 m",
      "weight": "6.9 kg"
    },
    "pokemon-rarity": "normal",
    "type": [
      "grass",
      "poison"
    ],
    "encounter": {
      "base-flee-rate": "0.1",
      "base-capture-rate": "0.2"
    },
    "spawn-chance": "0.69",
    "stats": {
      "base-attack": "118",
      "base-defense": "111",
      "base-stamina": "128",
      "max-cp": "1115",
      "max-hp": "113"
    },
    "resistant": [
      "water",
      "electric",
      "grass",
      "fighting",
      "fairy"
    ],
    "weaknesses": [
      "fire",
      "ice",
      "flying",
      "psychic"
    ],
    "quick-move": [
      {
        "name": "vine whip",
        "type": "grass",
        "base-damage": "7",
        "energy": "6",
        "move-duration-seg": "0.6"
      },
      {
        "name": "tackle",
        "type": "normal",
        "base-damage": "5",
        "energy": "5",
        "move-duration-seg": "0.5"
      }
    ],
    "special-attack": [
      {
        "name": "sludge bomb",
        "type": "poison",
        "base-damage": "80",
        "energy": "-50",
        "move-duration-seg": "2.3"
      },
      {
        "name": "seed bomb",
        "type": "grass",
        "base-damage": "55",
        "energy": "-33",
        "move-duration-seg": "2.1"
      },
      {
        "name": "power whip",
        "type": "grass",
        "base-damage": "90",
        "energy": "-50",
        "move-duration-seg": "2.6"
      }
    ],
    "egg": "2 km",
    "buddy-distance-km": "3",
    "evolution": {
      "candy": "bulbasaur candy",
      "next-evolution": [{
        "num": "002",
        "name": "ivysaur",
        "candy-cost": "25",
        "next-evolution": [{
          "num": "003",
          "name": "venusaur",
          "candy-cost": "100"
        }]
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    "num": "002",
    "name": "ivysaur",
    "generation": {
      "num": "generation i",
      "name": "kanto"
    },
    "about": "There is a bud on this Pokémon's back. To support its weight, Ivysaur's legs and trunk grow thick and strong. If it starts spending more time lying in the sunlight, it's a sign that the bud will bloom into a large flower soon.",
    "img": "https://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/002.png",
    "size": {
      "height": "0.99 m",
      "weight": "13.0 kg"
    },
    "pokemon-rarity": "normal",
    "type": [
      "grass",
      "poison"
    ],
    "encounter": {
      "base-flee-rate": "0.07",
      "base-capture-rate": "0.1"
    },
    "spawn-chance": "0.042",
    "stats": {
      "base-attack": "151",
      "base-defense": "143",
      "base-stamina": "155",
      "max-cp": "1699",
      "max-hp": "134"
    },
    "resistant": [
      "water",
      "electric",
      "grass",
      "fighting",
      "fairy"
    ],
    "weaknesses": [
      "fire",
      "ice",
      "flying",
      "psychic"
    ],
    "quick-move": [
      {
        "name": "razor leaf",
        "type": "grass",
        "base-damage": "13",
        "energy": "7",
        "move-duration-seg": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "vine whip",
        "type": "grass",
        "base-damage": "7",
        "energy": "6",
        "move-duration-seg": "0.6"
      }
    ],
    "special-attack": [
      {
        "name": "sludge bomb",
        "type": "poison",
        "base-damage": "80",
        "energy": "-50",
        "move-duration-seg": "2.3"
      },
      {
        "name": "solar beam",
        "type": "grass",
        "base-damage": "180",
        "energy": "-100",
        "move-duration-seg": "4.9"
      },
      {
        "name": "power whip",
        "type": "grass",
        "base-damage": "90",
        "energy": "-50",
        "move-duration-seg": "2.6"
      }
    ],
    "egg": "not in eggs",
    "buddy-distance-km": "3",
    "evolution": {
      "candy": "bulbasaur candy",
      "next-evolution": [{
        "num": "003",
        "name": "venusaur",
        "candy-cost": "100"
      }],
      "prev-evolution": [{
        "num": "001",
        "name": "bulbasaur",
        "candy-cost": "25"
      }]
    }
  },
.
.
.
```

Código .js:

```
import pokemon from "/pokemons.json";
const search = document.querySelector(".search");

const filtered = pokemon.filter((p) => {
  const title = search.value;
  return p.name === title
});

search.addEventListener("input", filtered);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import data from "./data/pokemon/pokemon.json" assert { type: "json" };

//console.log(data);
//section onde aparecerão os cards
const dataPokemon = document.querySelector("#data-pokemon");
//capturar input
const inputText = document.querySelector("#search");

//função do filtro
function filterName() {
  //pegar valor do input e transformar em minúsculo
  const inputTitle = inputText.value.toLowerCase();

  if (inputTitle !== "") {
    dataPokemon.innerHTML = "";
    const filteredPokemons = data.pokemon.filter((poke) => {
      return poke.name.toLowerCase() === inputTitle;
    });

    dataPokemon.innerHTML = "";

    filteredPokemons.map((poke) => {
      //implementar no HTML
      //adicionar sempre um novo elemento, já que o map percorre todos elementos do array
      dataPokemon.innerHTML += `<figure class='cards'>
                                  <h3 class='title-card'>${poke.name}</h3>
                                  <p>
                                    <strong>Generation:</strong>
                                    ${poke.generation.num} -
                                    ${poke.generation.name}
                                  </p>
                                  <img class='img-card'src=${poke.img}></img>
                                  <figcaption class='about-card'>${poke.about}
                                  </figcaption>
                                  <p>
                                    <strong>Type:</strong>
                                    ${poke.type.join(", ")}
                                  </p>
                                  <p>
                                    <strong>Weaknesses:</strong>
                                    ${poke.weaknesses.join(", ")}
                                    </p>
                                  <button class='read-more'>${"Detalhes"}</button>
                                </figure>`;
    });
  } else {
    fetch("./data/pokemon/pokemon.json").then((response) => {
      //Resposta convertida em json
      response.json().then((pokemon) => {
        //pegar dados pelo map
        //cada elemento do array vai ser poke
        //retornará separadamente
        pokemon.pokemon.map((poke) => {
          //implementar no HTML
          //adicionar sempre um novo elemento, já que o map percorre todos elementos do array
          dataPokemon.innerHTML += `<figure class='cards'>
                                      <h3 class='title-card'>${poke.name}</h3>
                                      <p>
                                        <strong>Generation:</strong>
                                        ${poke.generation.num} -
                                        ${poke.generation.name}
                                      </p>
                                      <img class='img-card'src=${
                                        poke.img
                                      }></img>
                                      <figcaption class='about-card'>${
                                        poke.about
                                      }
                                      </figcaption>
                                      <p>
                                        <strong>Type:</strong>
                                        ${poke.type.join(", ")}
                                      </p>
                                      <p>
                                        <strong>Weaknesses:</strong>
                                        ${poke.weaknesses.join(", ")}
                                        </p>
                                      <button class='read-more'>${"Detalhes"}</button>
                                    </figure>`;
        });
      });
    });
  }
}

//ouvinte do evento
inputText.addEventListener("input", filterName);
```

- Peguei o valor do input, vi se ele não era vazio e comparei com o name filtrado do json
- Zerei a section onde apareciam os cards
- criei o card a partir do pokemon filtrado pelo json (não criei uma div nova, apenas zerei a que já estavam os cards e adicionei o filtrado)
- Quando o input é zerado ele redesenha todos os cards do json

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Tente isso:

```
// Importe o JSON corretamente, ajustando o caminho para o arquivo 
pokemons.json
import pokemonData from "./pokemons.json";

const search = document.querySelector(".search");
const resultsContainer = document.querySelector(".results");

// Função para filtrar e exibir os resultados
function filterAndDisplayResults() {
  const inputValue = search.value.toLowerCase();
  const filteredPokemons = pokemonData.pokemon.filter((p) => {
    return p.name.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue);
  });

  // Limpe os resultados anteriores
  resultsContainer.innerHTML = "";

  // Adicione os resultados filtrados à lista
  filteredPokemons.forEach((pokemon) => {
    const pokemonDiv = document.createElement("div");
    pokemonDiv.textContent = pokemon.name;
    resultsContainer.appendChild(pokemonDiv);
  });
}

// Adicione o ouvinte de evento de input
search.addEventListener("input", filterAndDisplayResults);
```

Comment: Consegui resolver com base no que me mandou, mas mudei algumas coisas pra funcionar. Vou responder aqui, se quiser dar alguma sugestão de melhoria seria muito bom.